# How do I prevent viewpager from making network request, if the network request has already been made for all the pages

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-volley, viewpagerindicator

I have a viewpager with three pages that uses FragmentStatePagerAdapter.
The fragment for each page is same but the data changes depending on the position of the page. The inflation logic for each item on the page is defined in fragment's OnCreateView, and thats why each time new instance of fragment is inflated the network calls are repeated even though they have been already made on previous visit to that page.

My question is how do I prevent this. I am new to android and I know I am missing something here, IF my approach is wrong please point out about how should I prevent this behavior.

Some Code :
inside activity's oncreate

```
    ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpBooks);
    PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new BooksPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this, extras);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

inside viewpageradapter

```
public BooksPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, Bundle extras) {
    super(fm);
    this.extras = extras;
    this.cls = extras.getStringArray("cls");
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return BooksPageFrag.newInstance(extras, cls[position]);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return cls.length;
}
```

inside fragment :

```
@Override
public void onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    url = getArguments().getString("url");
    urlFare = getArguments().getString("Fare");
    Log.d("url sapf", url);
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity());
    getBooks();// HERE network calls are made
}
```

so what I want is if the fragement for a particular cls[position] is instantiated and data is fetched then on revisiting same position it should not make new network calls

Comment: What did you try? Show some code please

Comment: You may want to use `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead.

Comment: You can use the activity that hosts the pager to store downloaded data instead of the fragment itself or you could use a singleton class to store data for each fragment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use parcelable . I think you are using a list array of a class object
.Follow the following steps

1.) Implement parcelable in the class object 
2.)In the OnSavedInstanceState use the following code

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("key", mListParcel);
}`
```

3.) In the onCreate method use this code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
   /*Set Your RecyclerView Stuff here*/
   if(savedInstanceState!=null)
    {
         //Fragment has been loaded earlier\
         mArrayList=savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("key");
         //Use list here
      }
    else
    { 
        //Fragment New 
        // Make Request Here
    }
}
```